# Eigen: return type of 1-a.array()

Tags: c++, eigen

Assume type of 'a' is Vector3d and I wonder what's the type of 1-a.array(). I have this doubt because `a.cwiseProduct(b)` works but `(1-a.array()).cwiseProduct(b)` result in compilation error. What's the right way to write code like `(1-a.array()).cwiseProduct(b)`?

```
int main()
{   
    VectorXd a(3),b(3);
    a << 1,2,3;
    b << 2,3,4;
    // cout << (1-a.array()).cwiseProduct(b) << endl; //failed
    a = 1-a.array();
    cout << a.cwiseProduct(b) << endl; //works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to describe some code, please *show it*. Preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would also help if you told us *what* error you get. Please copy-paste it in full and complete into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cwiseProduct` only works on matrix expressions, not on array (element wise) expressions (where the "cwise" would be redundant). The easy options are to either cast the `(1-a.array())` expression to a matrix expression `(1-a.array()).matrix().cwiseProduct(b)` (at compile time, so free); or better yet, if you want to do element wise stuff, just use all array objects `(1-a.array()) * b.array()` (again, the compile time casts are free).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The expression can be rewritten without using `.array()`, by replacing the `1` with a vector of ones:

```
(Vector3d::Ones() - a).cwiseProduct(b)
```

This version is arguably somewhat cleaner, as the operations are easier to recognize than in the version with `.array()` since the bracket contains a simple difference between two vectors.

A further equivalent variant consists in using `.asDiagonal()` instead of `.cwiseProduct()`

```
(Vector3d::Ones() - a).asDiagonal() * b
```

Comment: This way is much more intuitive and I wonder if there's performance difference between .cwiseProduct() and .array() multipication?  asDiagonal() is interesting but bit of tricky.

Comment: There is no performance difference between these variants and the `.array()` multiplication. From a mathematical perspective `.asDiagonal()` is a more natural description than `.cwiseProduct()`, while the latter may be more familiar from a programming perspective.